# V9 - Problemas com a criação do objecto GprBEOFComponente - Produção

Tags: vb.net

Boa tarde, 
Criei um método para criação de uma OF, todos os objectos associados á OF são bem instanciados á excepção do GprBEOFComponente.
Localmente consigo executar o código, mas num servidor de produção, surge a seguinte mensagem:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'GprBE900.GprBEOFComponente'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{CE40951A-994A-4404-B354-F6E21175FBDB}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Conseguem ajudar?

```
    Private Function criaOrdemFabrico(ByVal artigoOF As String, ByVal alternativaOF As String, ByVal qtFabricada As Double, ByVal qtNecessaria As Double, ByVal qtOrdemFabrico As Double, ByVal isOFFilho As Boolean, ByVal OFPai As String, ByVal IDEnc As String, ByVal IDLinhaEncomenda As String, ByVal entidadeEnc As String, ByVal qtdEnc As Double) As GprBEOrdemFabrico

        Dim oListaFichaTecnica As New DataTable
        Dim oOrdemFabrico As New GprBEOrdemFabrico
        Dim oOFArt As New GprBEOFArtigo
        Dim oOFEnc As New GprBEOFEncomenda
        Dim oOFOperacao As New GprBEOFOperacao
        Dim oOFCentroTrabalho As New GprBEOFCentroTrabalho
        Dim oOFComponente As New GprBEOFComponente
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, suponho que este projeto esteja em VB.NET e estejam a usar como referência  os interop's disponibilizados pela PRIMAVERA, sendo assim pela mensagem pareçe claro que as DLL's que estão registadas na maquina de produção são diferentes das que forma usadas no projecto. Assim:

- Devem verificar os atributos abaixo, se não estiverem, devem recompilar  o projeto de acordo com a informação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Verificar qual as versões registadas na maquina de produção, para tal podem usar uma ferramenta como o [COM Explorer](https://download.cnet.com/COM-Explorer/3000-2206_4-10022464.html). Caso não sejam iguais recomendo apagar as mesmas e reinstalar de seguida o ERP.

Comment: Olá Sérgio.
Obrigado pela resposta.
Parece-me que esse possa ser exactamente o meu problema.
Assim que tiver disponibilidade para testar a solução no servidor de produção, envio-lhe o respectivo feedback.

Comment: A melhor forma de agradeçer é dar um upa na resposta. Fica a aguardar esse feedback

Comment: Parece-me justo Sérgio.
Acabei de testar após a sua sugestão e informo que o problema está ultrapassado.
Falha de principiante. :)
Agradeço o seu apoio.